# Will_Paginate - how to get an array of all paginated object ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, will-paginate, traversal

I'm using `will_paginate` **2.3.x** gem and I'm trying to get an array of all the ids of the objects that are in the WillPaginate::Collection. Is there a simple way to iterate **all** the items in the collection? With ActiveRecord collection this is simple:

```
all_ids = MyObject.find(:all).map { |o| o.id }
```

However, when paginated, the collection returns only the N elements that are in the first page:

```
not_all_ids = MyObject.paginate(:page => 1).map { |o| o.id }
```

What I want is to go through all the pages in the collection. Basically, I'm looking for a method that retrieves the next page. Any thoughts? thanks.

**EDIT** - I'm using rails 2.3. Also, I'm using pagination with some conditions but dropped them to simplify:

```
MyObject.paginate(:conditions => [...], :include => [...], :page => 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that :

```
ids = MyObject.select("id").paginate(:page => 1)
if ids.total_pages > 1
  (2..ids.total_pages).each do |page|
    ids << MyObject.select("id").paginate(:page => page)
  end
end
ids = ids.map(&:id)
```

But why using paginate in this case ?

```
ids = MyObject.select("id").map(&:id)
```

will be faster, and will use less resources ... if you're db contains 10000 elements and you're iterating 10 at a times you'll make 1000 cals to your db vs 1 :-)

ps: I'm using *.select("id")* so the request generated is :

```
SELECT id from users;
```

VS

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

I'm also using a nice shortcut *map(&:id)*, this is the equivalent of *.map { |o| o.id }*

Comment: I should note that I'm using some conditions on each paginate call, so hitting the DB for every page (and there are plenty) will be highly inefficient. I also forgot to mention I'm [still] using Rails 2.3, so `Something.select('id')` is `Something.all(:select => 'id')` for me.